# PHP/MySQL Insert Query

Tags: php, mysql, insert-query

For the life of me I can't get this insert query to work.

```
mysql_connect("**host**", "**username**", "**password**") or error("Could not connect: ".mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("**db_name**");
$db = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `pass_reset` (id,status,key,email) VALUES ('','0','$key','$email')");
```

It returns this error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'key,email) VALUES ('','0','','')' at line 1

Could someone help me with this? I'm literally pulling my hair out over this simple query.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try the following:

```
$db = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `pass_reset` (id,status,`key`,email) VALUES ('','0','$key','$email')");
```

Because `key` is a [reserved word by MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html), you must escape it with the backticks ``

Comment: It is a `key`word, you could say. Haha. Ha. I'll be going now.

Comment: @Shef, I tend to always back-tick all my field-/tablenames solves a lot of unknown problems!

Comment: @Nideo: So do I. I am blamed so often for that by coders who put much more weigh on readability and forget about functionality. :)

Answer (score 3):

`KEY` is a reserved word in MySQL, so you'd have to escape it with back ticks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try enclosing the column names with the grave accent?

```
(`id`,`status`,`key`,`email`)
```

Answer (score -1):

dont put php variable in '', it will surely work man

```
$db = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `pass_reset` (id,status,key,email) VALUES ('','0',$key,$email)");
```

Or

```
 $db = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `pass_reset` (id,status,key,email) VALUES ('0',$key,$email)");
```